# Actually download Media bytes with InstagramApiSharp

Tags: c#, instagram-api

Has anyone succesfully used library InstagramApiSharp to download media?
I am currently using the library and it works great but when calling the GetUserMediaByIdAsync() Method the resuling List(Of Media) has all the details but not the actual Bytes of each media.

It does has a Media.ImageBytes as Byte() but its null
Or I am supposed to manually download each media from the Media.Uri provided?

I know this is purely strict to InstagramApiSharp library but maybe someone has used it, all the examples out there (even on the code itself) show media details but do not use the actual media bytes.